# Is there any way to access SSL Certificate details using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, browser, ssl-certificate

Is it possible to access SSL Certificate details using Javascript? I need to show SSL Certificate information in a Popup or invoke SSL Certificate viewer in the browser as I have Payment gateway access. Please provide me a solution for this. Thanks in advance.